# How to apply CSS on custom buttons in tinyMCE active editor popup

Tags: javascript, css, tinymce-4

I want to add custom CSS in my tinyMCE active editor popup, attaching the screenshot for your reference.[image]

below is the reference code:

```
tinymce.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
title: 'Browse Image Gallery',
    file: "data/get_images_tiny.php",
        width: 500,
        height: 305,
        resizable: "no",
        inline: "yes",
        close_previous: "no",
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Upload Image from your PC',
            onclick: function () {
            //do something               
            }
        }, {
            text: 'Close',
            onclick: 'close'
            }]
        }
});
```

Comment: Can you supply a working demo? On https://jsfiddle.net or somewhere like that.

Comment: Can't you just target the class and style it?

Comment: Hi Andy thanks for your response but I can't target the style as it comes from javascript and there is no class element here. This is what it produces: <button tabindex="-1" type="button" role="presentation" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;"><span class="mce-txt">Upload Image</span></button>

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do is to override style, by defining your custom css file.

Tinymce init Configuration

```
editor_css : 'editor.css'
```

Then

```
.defaultSkin span.mce_upload {some_css: css_value}
```

Comment: Refer to this [article](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/integration-and-setup)

Comment: and also if I overwrite this default css, it will reflect in all buttons, which is just not required, I've also checked the link that you gave but did not find my answer

Comment: You need to try things on yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.mce-btn button` selector to add custom style for all buttons what has this selector.

You found it in the `skin.min.css`

There are also other selectors in it, like `.mce-primary button`

This css is at `[path/to/tinymce/]tinymce/js/tinymce/skins/lightgray`

where lightgray is the theme name.

You can also overwrite it in your `editor.css`

**UPDATE**

You can add  your custom css for your popups like this ([reference](http://archive.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x:popup_css)):

```
tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    popup_css : "/mypopup.css"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this:

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
    file : "data/get_images_tiny.php",
    title : 'Browse Image Gallery',
    width: 500,
    height: 305,
    resizable: "no",
    inline: "yes",
    close_previous: "no",
    buttons: [{
          text: 'Insert',
          classes: 'widget btn primary first abs-layout-item',
          onclick: 'close',
          id: 'insertButton'
      }, {
          text: 'Close',
          onclick: 'close',
      }]
});
```