# TinyMCE change existing button icon

Tags: javascript, jquery, tinymce, wysiwyg

I'm using TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor in my html form. I want to change icons (16x16 images) of existing toolbar buttons, i.e. bold button, italic button, etc. The idea is to put my own drawings instead of basic **B**, ***I***, etc icons.

I found how to add a brand new button with my custom icon to toolbar via `tinymce.Editor.addButton('myButton', {... 'image': '/path/to/my/drawing'})` method, but I still have no idea how to replace icons for already existing buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, but probably you know easier ways, so feel free to answer.

It could be done by creating your own skin for TinyMCE. But skins don't look easy to create and [TinyMCESkinCreator](http://skin.tinymce.com/) doesn't seem help in deep customization. So I found [cool third-party skin](http://tinymceplugins.com/plugins/lightgray-no-fonts-skin) which has evident place for storing of these icons - `img/sprites16px.png`. So I was able to redraw any of them in graphic editor.

I successfully replaced **B** letter for bold to russian letter **Ж** by editing the spritelist:

[image: my result]

Comment: How did you add that icon for inserting image?

Answer (score 3):

an other solution, in CSS (Work on IE 11, Firefox 67.x and Chrome 74) for TinyMce v5 :

[image: Image example]

Please note that the word `Gras` in  `...[aria-label="Gras"]` is a result of translate, so you must change it in your own code.

```css
    /*Hide original svg:*/
    .tox-tbtn[aria-label="Gras"] .tox-icon svg {
        display: none;
    }

    /*Dimensions of svg icon:*/
    .tox-tbtn[aria-label="Gras"] .tox-icon {
        display: list-item;
        list-style: none;
        width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
    }

    /*Svg icon:*/
    [aria-label='Gras'].tox-tbtn .tox-icon {
        background-image: url("/build/admin/images/tinyMceBoutonGras.svg");
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
    }
```

Here, the same example with SVG convert in Base64 :

```css
    /*Hide original svg:*/
    .tox-tbtn[aria-label="Gras"] .tox-icon svg {
        display: none;
    }

    /*Dimensions of svg icon:*/
    .tox-tbtn[aria-label="Gras"] .tox-icon {
        display: list-item;
        list-style: none;
        width: 18px;
        height: 18px;
    }

    /*Svg icon (In base64):*/
    [aria-label='Gras'].tox-tbtn .tox-icon {
        background-image: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center center;
    }
```

Hope this help,
Yan

Answer (score 0):

I am changing in ReactJS like this inside init object.

```
setup: function (editor) {
                editor.ui.registry.addIcon(
                  "underline",
                  '<svg width="16" height="16" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 27.75 31.75"><defs><style>.cls-1{fill:#4c5866;}</style></defs><g id="Layer_2" data-name="Layer 2"><g id="Layer_1-2" data-name="Layer 1"><g id="Underline"><path class="cls-1" d="M13.88,25.69A10.89,10.89,0,0,1,3,14.82V1.88a1.88,1.88,0,1,1,3.75,0V14.82a7,7,0,0,0,7.13,7.12A7,7,0,0,0,21,14.82V1.88a1.88,1.88,0,1,1,3.75,0V14.82A10.89,10.89,0,0,1,13.88,25.69Z"/><path class="cls-1" d="M25.88,31.75h-24a1.88,1.88,0,1,1,0-3.75h24a1.88,1.88,0,0,1,0,3.75Z"/></g></g></g></svg>'
                );
}
```

and it is working just fine.

Answer (score -1):

try this
https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-appearance/

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-add-custom-styles-to-wordpress-visual-editor/

[How to apply CSS on custom buttons in tinyMCE active editor popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37185129/how-to-apply-css-on-custom-buttons-in-tinymce-active-editor-popup)